# Cmd file put content of file in var with newline

Tags: batch-file, cmd, newline

i'm working on a cmd script.
In it i read a file and place the result in a variable
My file look like something like this:

First line
(Blank line)
Second line
(Blank line)
And it goes on like this

In my code i'm using this:

```
For /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (temp.txt) do set content=!content!%%x
```

As a result everithing is on one line i don't have my blank line :
First line second line ...
How can i get the blank line ?

Comment: Be careful - A batch environment variable is limited to 8191 characters, minus the length of the variable name. You will need a different strategy if any of your files exceed ~8kb.

Comment: thanks fortunately it will be maximum like 1k characters

Answer (score 1):

Your for loop doesn't fetch the empty line, because empty lines are skipped.
You need a trick, like prepending each line with a line number, with findstr.
And to add line feeds you can defined a variable containing a single line feed character (in the code the `\n` variable)

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
(set \n=^
%=do not delete this line=%
)

set "content="
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (`"findstr /n ^^ t7.bat"`) do (
    set "var=%%a"
    set "var=!var:*:=!"
    if defined content (
        set "content=!content!!\n!!var!"
    ) else set "content=!var!"
)

echo(!content!
```

This code has still some problems, with exclamation marks, but for simple file content it works

Comment: I tried to copy paste your code and place temp.txt instead of t.txt and content is empty , maybe i need to do more change in it i don't really know

Comment: @Nono Sorry, didn't test the code. I fixed it now